# Optimizing XQuery projection

Tags: sql-server, xml, projection, xquery

I'm getting some horrific performance from an XQuery projection in Sql Server.
What would be the best way to write the following transformation?

```
select DocumentData.query(
'<object type="dynamic">
    <state>
       <OrderTotal type="decimal">
          {fn:sum( 
              for $A in /object[1]/state[1]/OrderDetails[1]/object/state[1] 
               return ($A/ItemPrice[1] * $A/Quantity[1]))}      
       </OrderTotal>
       <CustomerId type="guid">
            {xs:string(/object[1]/state[1]/CustomerId[1])}
       </CustomerId>
       <Details type="collection">
           {/object[1]/state[1]/OrderDetails[1]/object}
       </Details>
    </state>
 </object>') as DocumentData
from documents
```

(I know the code is a bit out of context)

If I check the executionplan for this code, there is about 10+ joins going on.
Should I break this down to use for $var for each level in the structure?

For more context, this is what I'm trying to accomplish:
http://rogeralsing.com/2011/03/02/linq-to-sqlxml-projections/

I'm writing a "Linq to XQuery translator" / NoSQL Document DB emulator, filtering works like a charm, projections suffer from perf problems.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187508%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: do you have XML indexes?

Comment: Yepp , indexes are in place, value/path/property and primary. seems like the xquery projection is just horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article is quite useful:
[Performance Optimizations for the XML Data Type in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345118.aspx)

In particular it recommends that instead of writing paths of the form...

/object[1]/state[1]/CustomerId[1]

you should instead write...

(/object/state/CustomerId)[1]